# How do I get Flex to work in my react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flexbox

Basically I have two divs setup up and im trying to use flex box to easily size them so they both equally take up half the screen vertically using react. For some reason they are turning out looking like this.

[image: View]

Iv'e tried reinstalling npm but that didn't work at all, and i'm pretty sure my syntax is just fine.

This is my App.css

```
.wrapper,html,body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

  }

  .nav {
    background-color: red;
    flex: 1;

  }

  .main {
    background-color: blue;
    flex: 1;

  }
```

This is my App.js

```
import {Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import './App.css'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className = 'wrapper'>

        <div className = 'nav'>
          <text>hey</text>
        </div>

        <div className = 'main'>
        <text>hey</text>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

They should work if you remove `flex-direction: column;` - you actually want `flex-direction: row;`, which is the default.

Comment: That didn't work, I want the divs to stack on top of each other and take and have each be half the height of the screen.

Comment: Ah, I completely misunderstood "so they both equally take up half the screen vertically using react" - you want to set the height of the parent container to 100% of the height of the window - you can use `height: 100vh;` for that

Answer (score 0):

Your code is all fine, just need add **flex:1  to wrapper class**.
you can read more about flex here : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.wrapper,
html,
body {
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
     


}
  
.wrapper {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1;
}

.nav {
 background-color: red;
 flex: 1;
}

.main {
 background-color: blue;
 flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>

    <div class='nav'>
        <text>hey</text>
    </div>

    <div class='main'>
        <text>hey</text>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `flex: 1` prop inside the `.wrapper` css definition. The definition should look like this:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex:1;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

With `flex: 1` you're telling the wrapper to use all the available space. Otherwise, it just use what it needs no matter the height.

Here's the entire CSS:

```css
.wrapper,
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.nav {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1;
}

.main {
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 1;
}
```

See the result:
[image]

Anyway, I totally recommend using Bootstrap v4 which is [flexbox based by default](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#how-it-works).

Comment: This didn't work for some reason, the divs are still styled the same

Comment: It's working for me, see my output. I've just pasted the entire CSS code, just in case. Hope you can solve it.